# Spacing out updates in single instance

Tags: java, singleton

I am writing a platform game and i decided to layout the tiles in an unusual way.  Instead of making each tile its own object i made one object representing each type of block and i just put that block into my tile map array multiple times.  The problem is now when i call my tiles update method on the block it calls the update method on all the blocks on the map.  So now what i did is i passed the update method the coords of the tile.  So here is the problem, the update method gets called several times a second but i only want my blocks update action happening every 3 seconds, how will i accomplish this.  I found a temporary solution, but it doesnt work well by using a random number to determine if the update action should be performed.  Here is my current update method.  I cannot make each block its own instance, i tried it and the lag was unbearable.

```
Random random = new Random();

public void update(int x, int y, boolean inRange)
{
    if(random.nextInt(1000)==0)
    {
        double playerX = (panel.getCharacter().getX()+panel.getCharacter().getX()+panel.getCharacter().getWidth())/2;
        double playerY = (panel.getCharacter().getY()+panel.getCharacter().getY()+panel.getCharacter().getHeight())/2;
        int dispenserX = x*Block.WIDTH;
        int dispenserY = y*Block.HEIGHT;
        Point2D.Double player = new Point2D.Double(playerX, playerY);
        Point2D.Double dispenser = new Point2D.Double(dispenserX, dispenserY);
        double angle = calcAngle(dispenser, player);
        panel.addEntity(new EntityFireball(x*Block.WIDTH,y*Block.HEIGHT,angle,1));
        Music.playWav("dispenser");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want something to happen every three seconds, use a timer. If you have the same object referenced multiple times, any update to that object will be reflected by every reference, since they reference the same object.

Comment: exactly my problem so would i have to map all of the coordinates to seperate timers and then check how long its been since it was last checked.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just not have the same object for every tile?

Comment: but that would take a lot of memory to create that many objects

Comment: If these tiles are going to vary, then somewhere, somehow you have to allocate memory for each individual tile.

Comment: Get the program working first. Then optimize if *measurably* necessary.

Comment: i cnt test with the amount of lag each block produces

Comment: The bad news that if you need to represent individual state then you need to represent individual state. Are you running in a memory-constrained environment? How much memory do you believe you're actually using? How much memory do you think a typical tile-based game uses? Can you optimize by scrolling?

Comment: no its just that with living game entities they take up large amounts of memory and since i hold all the blocks in a matrix they take up memory even when they are not being used.  The jvm free memory continues getting lower until gc is run and then it is high again, however when all blocks are instances the memory stays low

Comment: is it possible to map an object three ways

Comment: @JoshSobel And what I'm saying is that you don't *need* to keep everything in memory at once, you can only keep the *useful* (read: visible, significant, etc.) things in memory. You cannot represent multiple states with a single state, by definition. How do you think we used to have infinite worlds in the days of 4-16K RAM? By loading in only the tiles we needed. How do you think modern games represent infinite worlds? The same way.

Comment: i know i only update the blocks that are visible to the player, however the physical block object still exists in memory, due to the fact that you cant delete objects in java